# PHP - Show Image From Database

Tags: php, sql, image

First of all, I've already known that there are similiar questions in stackoverflow about show images in php. But, my code is simple, & not complicated like the others, so I hope you can answer it in a simple way.

In database, I have `mahasiswa` table. It has these fields:

`nrp | nama | pass | jatah_sks | foto_profil`

I want the program to show `foto_profil` which is an image. The images are saved in folder `propic`. This is my code:

```
$sql4 = "select foto_profil from mahasiswa"
        . " where nrp=".$nrp;
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, $sql4);
if (!$result4) {
      die("<h3>SQL Error</h3>" . $sql4);
}
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);

<img src="propic/<?php echo $row4['foto_profil'] ?>"/>
```

The code shows no errors, but `foto_profil` won't showed up. It just shows an break-image icon. How is the right code? Please explain your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing php and html here.. You want this:

```
$sql4 = "select foto_profil from mahasiswa"
        . " where nrp=".$nrp;
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, $sql4);
if (!$result4) {
      die("<h3>SQL Error</h3>" . $sql4);
}
while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
    echo '<img src="propic/' . $row4['foto_profil'] . '"/>';
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't write that "while" line. Thanks